# how to count rows based on column values null and not null

Tags: oracle, group-by

May be this question is a duplicate of another, I already explored couple of similar questions here but I didn't find similar one. Please suggest if you find a link to similar question.

My problem is, I have a table say CLIENTS as below

```
BRANCH     CLNTID      ACCNT      FACID
------ ---------- ---------- ----------
   201      10001     123400     110021

   201      10001     123401

   201      10001     123402     110023

   201      10001     123403

   201      10001     123404     110025

   201      10001     123405

   201      10001     123406     110027

   201      10001     123407     110028
```

so on... many rows.
Now I want to write a query to give output like this

```
Branch   clntid   facid_null   facid_not_null

 201       10001      3              5
```

I want to find facid colmun count for facid=null and facid !=null for each branch and each clntid.

I wrote the below query but its fetching only one count either facid is null or facid is not null.

```
select branch,clntid,count(*)
from clnt
where facid is null
group by branch, clntid;
```

Please help me to find both counts in a single query using GROUP BY and as well as OVER (PARTITION BY ) clauses.

Thanks in advance.
Vivek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregate function [COUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions046.htm#SQLRF00624) counts all not null occurrences, so you can simply use count(facid) to count the facid_not_null column and you can use a similar technique and first swap the null and not null for the facid_null column. Here is a working example:

```
SQL> create table clnt (branch,clntid,accnt,facid)
  2  as
  3  select 201, 10001, 123400, 110021 from dual union all
  4  select 201, 10001, 123401, null from dual union all
  5  select 201, 10001, 123402, 110023 from dual union all
  6  select 201, 10001, 123403, null from dual union all
  7  select 201, 10001, 123404, 110025 from dual union all
  8  select 201, 10001, 123405, null from dual union all
  9  select 201, 10001, 123406, 110027 from dual union all
 10  select 201, 10001, 123407, 110028 from dual
 11  /

Table created.

SQL> select branch
  2       , clntid
  3       , count(case when facid is null then 1 end) facid_null
  4       , count(facid) facid_not_null
  5    from clnt
  6   group by branch
  7       , clntid
  8  /

    BRANCH     CLNTID FACID_NULL FACID_NOT_NULL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
       201      10001          3              5

1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select branch
      ,clntid
      ,count(*)                as num_rows
      ,count(facid)            as not_nulls
      ,count(*) - count(facid) as nulls
  from clnt
 group 
    by branch
      ,clntid;
```

Comment: +1 for making me remember count only counts the non null values